# Alpha ggplot2 not working when inside a for loop structure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have issues iteratively adding geom_ribbon layers over a ggplot2 and making sure ribbons are transparent.

If I follow the manual/hard-coded approach:

```r
bla<-ggplot(plot_fcst)
bla<-bla+geom_line(aes(y=Optimal,x=week))
bla<-bla+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=get(paste("lower",bands[1]*100,sep="")),ymax=get(paste("upper",bands[1]*100,sep="")),x=week),alpha=alp[1])
bla<-bla+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=get(paste("lower",bands[2]*100,sep="")),ymax=get(paste("upper",bands[2]*100,sep="")),x=week),alpha=alp[2])
bla<-bla+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=get(paste("lower",bands[3]*100,sep="")),ymax=get(paste("upper",bands[3]*100,sep="")),x=week),alpha=alp[3])
```

**Example Plot1: alpha shading behaving as expected:**

[image: Example Plot1: alpha shading behaving as expected]

But if I iteratively add the ribbon layers, alpha is set to match the darkest ribbon. Therefore I don't reckon the issue is the one answered here: [Alpha transparency not working in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648698/alpha-transparency-not-working-in-ggplot2)

```r
bands <- seq(0.5,0.9,by=0.1)
alp <- seq(.3,.1,by=-0.05)

ggplot_fcst<-ggplot(plot_fcst)+geom_line(aes(y=Optimal,x=week))     

for(i1 in 1:length(bands)){
     ggplot_fcst<-ggplot_fcst+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=get(paste("lower",bands[i1]*100,sep="")),ymax=get(paste("upper",bands[i1]*100,sep="")),x=week),alpha=alp[i1])
}
```

**Example plot2: Alpha wrongly set to match highest value:**

[image: Example plot2: Alpha wrongly set to match highest value]

Answer (score 3):

Your problem, as far as I can tell, has nothing to do with the alpha value. I have used the `economics` dataset to create some dummy data. You can see I have replicated your code below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

bands <- seq(0.5,0.9,by=0.1)
alp <- seq(.3,.1,by=-0.05)

data("economics")

plot_fcst <- data.frame(week = economics$date, 
                        Optimal = economics$pce, 
                        lower50 = economics$pce*0.8,
                        upper50 = economics$pce/0.8, 
                        lower60 = economics$pce*0.7,
                        upper60 = economics$pce/0.7, 
                        lower70 = economics$pce*0.6,
                        upper70 = economics$pce/0.6, 
                        lower80 = economics$pce*0.5,
                        upper80 = economics$pce/0.5, 
                        lower90 = economics$pce*0.4,
                        upper90 = economics$pce/0.4)

ggplot_fcst<-ggplot(plot_fcst)+geom_line(aes(y=Optimal,x=week))     

for(i1 in 1:length(bands)){
  ggplot_fcst <- ggplot_fcst+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=get(paste("lower",bands[i1]*100,sep="")),ymax=get(paste("upper",bands[i1]*100,sep="")),x=week),alpha=alp[i1])
}

ggplot_fcst
```

[image]

Now, this plot looks much like yours, only one ribbon is visible and it is the wrong alpha level. `ggplot2` gives us the ability to investigate the structure of the `ggplot` object using the `ggplot_build` command. I'll not go into too much detail here as to what the resulting object contains but we are interested in the `data`. This provides a table for each layer in the plot with all the information that `ggplot` need to create that layer. Since the first layer is the line, we are interested in the lines after 1:

```r
built <- ggplot_build(ggplot_fcst)

head(built$data[[2]])
#>      x   ymin    ymax PANEL group colour   fill size linetype alpha
#> 1 -915 202.96 1268.50     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1   0.3
#> 2 -884 204.20 1276.25     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1   0.3
#> 3 -853 206.52 1290.75     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1   0.3
#> 4 -823 205.16 1282.25     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1   0.3
#> 5 -792 207.24 1295.25     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1   0.3
#> 6 -762 210.32 1314.50     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1   0.3
head(built$data[[3]])
#>      x   ymin    ymax PANEL group colour   fill size linetype alpha
#> 1 -915 202.96 1268.50     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1  0.25
#> 2 -884 204.20 1276.25     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1  0.25
#> 3 -853 206.52 1290.75     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1  0.25
#> 4 -823 205.16 1282.25     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1  0.25
#> 5 -792 207.24 1295.25     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1  0.25
#> 6 -762 210.32 1314.50     1    -1     NA grey20  0.5        1  0.25
```

We can see that, for layer 2 (`i1` = 1), the alpha is correctly set at 0.3, while layer 3 (`i1` = 2) has alpha of 0.25. The `ymin` and and `ymax` columns show the problem: both ribbons have the same values. Rather than the alpha being incorrectly set to the highest level, each layer has the right alpha but the `ymin` and `ymax` variables are set to the last value in the for loop.

ggplot's lazy evaluation means that the `get` functions aren't called until you plot the chart, at which point it looks for the value of `i1` and assigns `lower90` and `upper90` to all layers.

What you can do, is get rid of the `get` calls altogether and use `aes_string` with the paste calls:

```r
ggplot_fcst<-ggplot(plot_fcst)+geom_line(aes(y=Optimal,x=week))

for(i1 in 1:length(bands)){
  ggplot_fcst <- ggplot_fcst+geom_ribbon(aes_string(ymin=paste("lower",bands[i1]*100,sep=""),ymax=paste("upper",bands[i1]*100,sep=""),x="week"),alpha=alp[i1])
}

ggplot_fcst
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To piggyback on @Eumenedies's answer to use `aes_string()` instead of `get()`, consider `Map` (or its parent call, `mapply`) since you are passing equal length vectors, *lower bands*, *upper bands*, and *alp* into a same process. Notice two the use of `paste0` and vectorizing it across *bands*.

```
ggplot_fcst <- ggplot(plot_fcst) + geom_line(aes(y=Optimal,x=week)) +
               Map(function(l, u, a) geom_ribbon(aes_string(ymin=l, ymax=u, x='week'), alpha=a),
                   paste0("lower",bands*100), paste0("upper",bands*100), alp)

ggplot_fcst
```